# STM32 HAL USART drivers: How does this syntax work?

Tags: c, syntax, embedded, stm32, hal

I am learning about STM32 programming and trying to implement simple asynchronous serial communication using USART peripheral on GPIO pins.

The HAL [manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/45/27/9c/32/76/57/48/b9/DM00189702.pdf/files/DM00189702.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00189702.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A4964%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C121%2C166%2C0%5D) describes how to use HAL USART drivers:

1. Declare a **USART_HandleTypeDef** structure
2. Implement  **HAL_USART_MspInit()**

   - Enable USART & GPIO clocks
   - Configure GPIOs
3. Program the communication parameters in the **USART_InitTypeDef**
4. Call **HAL_USART_Init()**

As I wrote my code, I declared the USART_HandleTypeDef, instinctively filled my USART_InitTypeDef structure and started to fill the HandleTypeDef:

```
  USART_HandleTypeDef UsartHandle;

  USART_InitTypeDef UsartInit;
  UsartInit.BaudRate   = 9600;
  UsartInit.WordLength = USART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  UsartInit.StopBits   = USART_STOPBITS_1;
  UsartInit.Parity     = USART_PARITY_NONE;
  UsartInit.Mode       = USART_MODE_TX_RX;

  UsartHandle.Instance = USART6;
  UsartHandle.Init     = &UsartInit;
  /* do I really have to init EVERY data field? */

  HAL_USART_Init(&UsartHandle);
```

I then noticed that there's many data fields to fill. Referring to code examples in the manual and on the web, I noticed nobody actually defines all of the USART_HandleTypeDef fields - they somehow combine the HandleTypeDef and InitTypeDef in one step, like this:

```
UART_HandleTypeDef UartHandle;

UartHandle.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
UartHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_DATABITS_8;
UartHandle.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
UartHandle.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
UartHandle.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
UartHandle.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
UartHandle.Init.Instance = USART1;
HAL_UART_Init(&UartHandle);
```

How does this work? What part of C syntax do I have to learn, to understand **where did that** UartHandle.**Init**.xxx **come from?**
Is it possible to do it "the long way", as I planned to? If I don't fill every datafield of HandleTypeDef, where do they get initialized?

**PS.** I am not using STM32 recommended IDEs or CubeMX, working on Linux, using PlatformIO. Board: STM32F746 discovery kit

**PPS.** I am really unsure whether to put this question here or on electronics stack. Please correct me or move the question there if it's not suitable for this stackexchange.

Comment: The ST "HAL" is not really much of an API, it is more of a series of wrapper functions around "scary hardware registers". There's no particular C syntax secret behind this, it is all about understanding the strange ST library.

Comment: Regarding your PPS: questions about microcontroller firmware are perfectly on-topic on both sites. But please never cross-post on both sites at once! If you have questions that are in the borderland of SW/HW, the EE site should be used. In general,  questions about things like microcontroller drivers get better answers over at EE.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the PPS clarification.  
Also, it's a good feeling to know I'm not the only one who thinks the ST library is weird...but as beginner in STM32 I didn't want to dive into baremetal programming straight away.

Comment: Simple answer. Do not use the bloatware. Just use bare registers.

Comment: And for the uC programming you need to know C every well. Spend more time learning this language Your question shows that you do not know C. You have learned something without good understanding of the basic topics

Comment: @PeterJ_01
Well, I am a student and not (yet) a professional. I don't plan to become a grandmaster of C, before programming my first uC programs. Because that is what interests me and I like to learn by doing. Please point me to the right chapter in "good understanding of C basics", if you know the answer...
Regarding bloatware, I agree with you and will consider bare-register option for sure.

Comment: Some things cannot be learned by doing. You need to know and understand the basics.

Comment: You are asking a good question and it is not about experience, it doesnt make obvious sense how the structure is initialized.  if global then it is .bss and one would expect it to be zeroed.  But if local then its on the stack and one would expect it not to be.  Perhaps it is just dumb luck.  Chicken and egg problem but once the uart is up you can dump the contents of the structure and/or if you have SWD (stlink, jlink, etc) you can dump the structure as well.  Also look at the disassembly.

Comment: What you are doing is considered baremetal as you have no operating system, because it feels so much like application programming, it feels more like it isnt baremetal, and you are missing most of the baremetal experience with these libraries.  I find the direct register method much simpler, but YMMV.  What you need are tools, learn to disassemble your code, get something with an stlink on it, the nucleo or discovery boards are cheaper than a standalone stlink (well depends) there is a jlink purple board thing for pretty cheap that works well.  get a uart solution.

Comment: master the toolchain, start with gnu then perhaps others.  for example, for this question can you find this structure and this code that is filling in the structure in a disassembly?  does that lead to any insight as to what if anything is going on? (smells like dumb luck to me).

Comment: @old_timer thanks for your advice! I do have a board with USB+stlink on it, so I will try to find my answers with GDB... meanwhile I'll get myself some reading on STM32 programming without HAL :)

Comment: some of the nucleo boards have the uart hooked up through the debug end so one usb connection gives you usb uart and stlink and the pseudo thumb drive interface for dropping .bin files on.  and many of those you can use the stlink on other cortex-m chips even from other vendors, if you have one with jumpers you can remove.  For this question focus on examining the hal library, what code reads that structure, and examine what the compiler produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does this work? What part of C syntax do I have to learn, to
>   understand where did that UartHandle.Init.xxx come from?

This is basic C struct syntax.  The `USART_HandleTypeDef` struct contains an instance of a `USART_InitTypeDef` struct named `Init`.  You can think of it as a nested struct.  You can reference the members of nested structs with repeated '`.`'s.  Note that, the `Init` member is NOT *a pointer* to a `USART_InitTypeDef` struct.  It's literally a complete `USART_InitTypeDef` instance contained within a `USART_HandleTypeDef` instance.

> Is it possible to do it "the long way", as I planned to?

Yes, except your code contains an error.  You need to make the assignment like this.

```
UsartHandle.Init     = UsartInit;    // Note no `&`
```

Remember that the `Init` member of `USART_HandleTypeDef` is not a pointer but a complete struct.  Therefore you need to assign it with a complete struct, not a pointer.

But realize that when you define your `UsartInit` variable, you are allocating space for an instance of the struct.  If `UsartInit` is a function local variable then that space is likely on the stack.  Your initialization statements are initializing your copy of the struct.  Then when you assign `UsartInit` to `UsartHandle.Init` the compiler creates code that will copy the entire contents of the struct.  After the copy, if your `UsartInit` is a local variable, it will go out of scope and be deallocated.

It's really not necessary to define and allocate space for your own `USART_InitTypeDef` struct and then copy the entire struct into `UsartHandle.Init`.  `UsartHandle` already contains space allocated for its `USART_InitTypeDef` member.  So it's more efficient to simply initialize the `UsartHandle.Init` member directly, like the ST example code does.

> If I don't fill every datafield of HandleTypeDef, where do they get
>   initialized?

You don't need to fill every datafield of `USART_HandleTypeDef`.  Refer to the HAL Reference Manual to learn what you need to initialize.  You probably need to initialize only the `Instance` and `Init` members.  The remaining members are used internally by the HAL USART driver and they will be initialized and used by the driver functions (you can think of them as private variables if that helps).  The designer of the API named that struct member "Init" as a cue to you that this is what you need to initialize.  The ST example code provides further evidence of what you need to initialize.

[Several experienced developers on Stack Overflow advise against using the ST HAL and encourage people to develop their own drivers based on the device's Reference Manual.  Realize that these developers have years of experience, they've worked with a variety of microcontroller families and peripherals, and they're capable of understanding the Reference Manual and writing drivers from scratch.  I agree that the ST HAL adds some bloat that might be detrimental to some applications.  But I disagree that beginners should avoid using the ST HAL.  The ST HAL works well enough for many applications and it is easier for beginners to use than writing their own drivers from scratch (especially given the many examples provided with the HAL).]

Comment: Whoa, thank you very much for your time and answer!
I later noticed my mistake of putting the & in front of UsartInit. The "Instance" member requires an address, not the Init >.<
Now that you explained, it makes perfect sense why people do it that way and not as I have imagined.
Regarding HAL: I ended up looking at register-level tutorials and reading the docs, to understand what is going on. However, I still plan to use HAL (or some other libs) for my programs, for now. Thanks again!

Comment: This question and answer would be very helpful for a newbie in STM32 like me. Thank you.